# HTTP Post Request not working throwing error "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined

Tags: javascript, post, http-post

I'm pretty new to javascript and am working on an integration system.

This is a small integration system, so I can't use Ajax or add any other normal web technologies, I just need to use Javascript to send a HTTP POST and get response only after success, so my first goal is to be able to send that POST message

I have written code but i am getting error

> Exception in map activity: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined.

```
function abc(){
  var url = "https://na10.saourt.com/se/sendData";
  var method = "POST";
  var postData ="[{\"name\":\"anderson\",\"ContactEmail\":\"ad@gmail.com\"}]";
  var async = true;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onload = function () {
      var status = request.status;
      var data = request.responseText;
  }
  request.open(method, url, async);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth 123");
  request.setRequestHeader("securityToken", "123@abs");
  request.send(postData);
}
```

Comment: Without any idea of what this "integration system" runs on, and what it supports, we can't really help you. `XMLHttpRequest` is mostly a browser based method, but if you don't have access to it, you must have access to something else, maybe the underlying OS, otherwise how will you send a request.

Comment: Did you mean to have a `"` at the beginning of `postData`? It looks like you forgot to include a quote to start the string.

Comment: @adeneo i had written same as it is what i have posted here for success fail case like: function sddf(){return sucess}; so not an matter of integration system

Comment: If you're running this in a browser, there's no reason `XMLHttpRequest` would not be defined ? And `XMLHttpRequest` ***IS*** ajax, the thing you're claiming you can't use ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending an empty/basic post request?